# How to write one line of code that prints with generator fibonacci in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, generator, fibonacci

I am having a problem with print and generator. I need to:

> In addition to the above generators, write one line of code that prints the list of all the numbers (which is different from "all the numbers") that are less than 1000 and also divisible by 3 in the Fibonacci sequence, starting with 0, 1

My generators:

```
def fibonacci(x,y):
    a, b= x, y
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def fibonacci_until(x,y,n):
    a, b = x, y
    while b <=n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

My attempt for this:

```
print([for f in fibonacci(0,1) if ((f % 3) == 0) and (f<1000)])
```

Comment: `print([0, 3, 21, 144])` – No one said you would *have* to use the generators… 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with your `fibonacci_until` generator,

```
[f for f in fibonacci_until(0,1, 1000) if f % 3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need this modification:

```
def fibonacci_until(x,y,n):
    a, b = x, y
    while b <=n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print([f for f in fibonacci_until(0,1, 1000) if ((f % 3) == 0)])
```

You had wrong array generation and also should use method which does not go infinitely :)